# Angular UI-Select Multiple Select with Angular-xeditable

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Fist of all I want tell you I am beginner of Angular UI Select and Angular-xeditable.

I am using Angular UI Select this: [Angylar UI Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

I am using for Edit In Place this: [Angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/)

I tried to use both of together and I already tried [Basic Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/K9alAMAzvUqCY7Or8RwY?p=preview), It is working fine. After that I add "`multiple`"to ui-select. It is also working fine and can select multiple items.

After I convert to edit in place using instruction of [This](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#uiselect), It is not working properly. Can't see selected item only see dash and can't see select name while selecting.

This is my code:

HTML Code:

```
<div editable-ui-select="selected.value" multiple data-e-name="name" name="name" data-e-ng-model="item.name" e-multiple >
    <editable-ui-select-match>
        {{$item.name}}
    </editable-ui-select-match>
    <editable-ui-select-choices repeat="item in (itemArray | filter: $select.search) track by item.id">
        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
    </editable-ui-select-choices>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.itemArray = [
    {id: 1, name: 'first'},
    {id: 2, name: 'second'},
    {id: 3, name: 'third'},
    {id: 4, name: 'fourth'},
    {id: 5, name: 'fifth'},
];

$scope.selected = { value: $scope.itemArray[0] };
```